# Does every conformal structure on a torus come from one of these specific embeddings in $\mathbb R^3$?

Tags: complex-geometry, riemann-surfaces, conformal-geometry

In the answers to this question:
https://mathoverflow.net/questions/53999/
they say that every Riemann surface can be realized as a smooth surface embedded in $\mathbb R^3$.

**Question**: Does every conformal structure on the torus arise from a smooth embedding of the torus in $\mathbb R^3$ given by taking the "standard torus" and applying an invertible linear transformation of $\mathbb R^3$ to it?

Comment: So I guess the "standard torus" is some torus formed by taking some circle in the plane and rotating that plane around some axis that doesn't cross through that circle. Really a family of tori.   I don't even know if given two tori of this form, one is always conformally equivalent to some invertible linear transformation applied to the other.

Comment: Is it correct the statement that at least for a purely imaginary $\tau$ parameter (the complex modulus of the flat torus) there is a "standard torus" with radii $R$ and $r$ such that $\tau=i \frac{r/R}{\sqrt{1+r^2/R^2}}$? I am just thinking that such standard torus has an induced metric given by (in toroidal coordinates) $ds^2=r^2 d\phi^2 + (R+r\cos\phi)^2 d\theta^2$  and is conformal to $d\varphi^2+d\theta^2$ with $\varphi=\frac{r}{R}\int^\phi \frac{d\phi}{1+\frac{r}{R}\cos \phi }$. I don't know how to get this from a $\pi/2$ rotation in the tangent planes.